# Random failing of SSL (SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL) in macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, certificate, curl, openssl, kaspersky

On Apple Mac running Mojave (10.14.3 - but had the error since I upgraded to Mojave) I  regularly (but randomly) get SSL errors when trying to connect using CURL on a command line so for example:

```
curl -vvvvv https://bbc.co.uk
* Rebuilt URL to: https://bbc.co.uk/
*   Trying 151.101.192.81...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to bbc.co.uk (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
  CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to bbc.co.uk:443
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to bbc.co.uk:443
```

the same error occurs to any https call

```
curl https://google.co.uk
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to google.co.uk:443
```

A reboot always fixes this but is not always convenient.  Has anyone come across this and have a fix?

This then (obviously) stops thinks like brew commands working and git etc

I tried running:

```
security verify-cert -L -c /etc/ssl/cert.pem
Cert Verify Result: CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED
```

whilst running:

```
security verify-cert -L -c /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem
...certificate verification successful.
```

so moved away `/etc/ssl/cert.pem` and tried to symlink it to `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem` but still no joy.

Some other info:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018
```

```
which openssl
/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/openssl
```

I also tried:

```
networksetup -setv6off Wi-Fi
```

using wget:

```
wget https://google.co.uk
--2019-03-26 10:35:10--  https://google.co.uk/
Resolving google.co.uk... 216.58.201.35
Connecting to google.co.uk|216.58.201.35|:443... connected.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

but that also made no difference.  Web browsing works fine so https is getting through the network ok.

Other notes, I have Kaspersky Internet Security (KIS) installed (which fails to open preferences, presumably because it's failing to do some kind of SSL call in the background) KIS is configured to not scan https connections (or whatever the setting was).  I also run MAMP and when php scripts are trying to talk to external servers (API calls etc) they all fail to connect presumably down to the same openssl error?

My guess is some network service needs to be restarted but I am more of an Ubuntu sysadmin than MacOS so don't know the commands.

help??!?? :-)

**EDIT:**  I noticed the line:

```
* Connected to bbc.co.uk (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
```

above which is clearly odd as it shouldn't try and connect to the localhost, so on a hunch I killed KIS and it then started working!!!  (I tried just disabling security but that made no difference) Happy Days!

Now though, if I try and restart KIS it won't startup properly (just hangs with a "starting..." message in the middle of the box).  So i might just remove KIS and look for an alternative.  :-(

Comment: To a large extent, security software is scareware that breaks things and increases your attack surface. Your Mac has many mitigations already, particularly Gatekeeper and XProtect. Maybe consider not using any third-party security software.

Comment: The above comment is truly terrible advice. If you will use your computer like a normal person you need security software. We can discuss which software works best, but the claims @DSchlachter makes are foolish and should not be taken seriously.

Answer (score 2):

Try shutting down kaspersky just like the above comment suggested. Or you can try to disable SSL interception following this guide found on the Kaspersky forums.

1. Open Kaspersky Internet Security
2. Go to

   > Settings -> Additional -> Network -> Do not scan encrypted connections.
3. Reboot

Answer (score 0):

similar situation, macbook pro, problem with Kaspersky Internet Security. After the process is complete, everything works.

Comment: So, basically, you’re offering random success as an antidote to random failure?